# Ho to properly use testing.B.N

Tags: go

I'm reading the book about Go and cannot figure out why the next code is not valid for benchmarking:

```
func BenchmarkFiboI(b *testing.B) {
 for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
 _ = fibo1(i)
 }
}
```

But the next if valid:

```
func BenchmarkFiboIV(b *testing.B) {
 for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
 _ = fibo1(10)
 }
}
```

Comment: Neither would probably work as the `_ =` asignment might trigger a complete optimisation to not executing fibo1 at all. The first has a problem as fibo1 probably has not a O(1) execution time and calling it with increasing i makes _interpreting_ the result complicated in the sense of "unreproducable". The second is "better" but still bad as it doesn't benchmark fibo1 but only fibo1(10).

Answer (score 1):

The benchmarking system uses `N` [very explicitly as an iteration count](https://pkg.go.dev/testing#hdr-Benchmarks), and *not* as a parameter to any code being benchmarked:

> The benchmark function must run the target code b.N times. During benchmark execution, b.N is adjusted until the benchmark function lasts long enough to be timed reliably.

Your first example is, therefore incorrect in a way likely to produce invalid results. The second example is correct, but to get more data on different inputs, you'd likely want several similar benchmarks passing different values to `fibo1`:

```
func BenchmarkFiboIV10(b *testing.B) {
 for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
 _ = fibo1(10)
 }
}
func BenchmarkFiboIV100(b *testing.B) {
 for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
 _ = fibo1(100)
 }
}
func BenchmarkFiboIV1000(b *testing.B) {
 for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
 _ = fibo1(1000)
 }
}
```